# Idea Intellij: can't increase heap size

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, environment-variables, heap-memory

I've been working with a library that demanded more heap space that was provided. So I tried to increase the heap space:

first I added an environment variable on Windows: going to

**Computer - Settings - Environment Variables - System Variables** **-** adding *JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx2024M*.

Then I went to Idea Intellij and tried to set a big enough heap size there too:

[image]

However when I run this code:

```
    long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    System.out.println(heapSize);

    long heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    System.out.println(heapFreeSize);
```

It prints out 128974848 and 124872256 bytes, which translates to 128 and 124 MBytes. How would I fix it and increase the heap size for real?

Answer (score 2):

The "Build process heap size" option, as its name says, increases the heap size for the build process, not for your application. To increase the heap size for your application, add an -Xmx option to the "VM options" field in the settings of the run configuration that you use to run your application.

Answer (score -2):

"Help" >> "Edit Custom VM Options" >> edit -Xmx parameter

Comment: This changes the heap size of the IDE, not of the user's application.

Comment: Ah, sorry( i was inattentive.